# Search and delete file in all local drives

Tags: windows, batch-file, find, delete-file

I would like to know if anyone knows how to make a batch search for a file by name on all local drives and delete it when found, so it is permanently deleted and not just in the recycle bin.

So far I have `DEL /S /P "123.MSN"` though this doesn't search beyond the current directory the batch is found in.

Comment: also found the following which might be handy to icorperate (as this also finds USB drives and so on) `echo LIST VOLUME > temp.txt && diskpart /s temp.txt && del /q temp.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this for each drive letter

`del C:\123.msn /f /s /q`

Just replace `C:\` with the drive or if unknown you might be able to do this recursively for all drives, see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/132685/batch-scripting-iterate-over-drive-letters). This will search the entire drive for the file, and if found, delete.

Also, you are using the `/p` switch which will prompt to delete. I wasn't sure if it was meant to be `/q` which suppresses confirmation. The `/f` will delete read only files, and the files won't go to the recycle bin, they will just be deleted.